# Display nested data on select option with KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

What I need is to display the nested data from *properties* and *implements* from my **couchdb** **json** data.

I managed to do that with JavaScript to hide and show the selected div from my select, but it only displays them at the first row. The other rows is not affected. Maybe I have some problem with my JavaScript or my `foreach` from knockout is not placed right.

If the selected option is Properties to display Properties data on it ex.

```
Converter: 8
Description: ""
EnumTypeName: ""
Name: "MainFile"
ValidationType: 4
```

And for implements:

```
TypeName: "ITSR2.Bricks.Access.IAccessBrick"
```

Not at the same time btw :P.

I searched and looked in documentation of knockout, but couldn't find anything.

Here is my **Index**:

```
<ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion" data-bind="foreach:myfield">
      <li  data-bind="with: value">
        <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>
        <p data-bind="text: Name"></p>
        </div>
          <div class="collapsible-body">
          <p data-bind="text: TypeName"></p>
          <p data-bind="text: AssemblyName"></p>
             <div class="row">
                  <form class="col s12">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col s6 m6">
                        <div class="col s6 m6">
                            <label>Select</label>
                            <select class="browser-default" onchange="showDiv(this)">
                              <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Choose your option</option>
                              <option value="Properties">Properties</option>
                              <option value="Implements">Implements</option>
                            </select>
                        </div><!-- end col s6 -->
                        <div class="col s6 m6" >
                        <div id="Properties" style="display: none;">
                        <p>Properties</p>
                          <ul data-bind="foreach: Properties.Properties">
                            <b>Name:</b> <span data-bind="text: $data.Name"></span></br>
                            <b> Validation Type: </b><span data-bind="text: $data.ValidationType"></span></br>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div id="Implements" style="display: none;">
                        <p>Implements</p>
                           <ul data-bind="foreach: Implements.Interfaces">
                            <b>Name:</b> <span data-bind="text: $data.TypeName"></span></br>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                        </div><!-- end col s6 -->
                      </div>
                    </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

My **Main.Js** file with the *viewModel* and how i retrieve my *data*:

```
 function showDiv(elem){
   if(elem.value == 'Properties'){
    document.getElementById('Properties').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('Implements').style.display = "none";
  } 
  else if(elem.value == 'Implements'){
      document.getElementById('Properties').style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById('Implements').style.display = "block";
  }
  else{
      document.getElementById('Properties').style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById('Implements').style.display = "none";
  }
}

function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.myfield =  ko.observableArray([]);


}

var db = new PouchDB('http://localhost:5984/helloworld');

var vm = new ViewModel();

db.query("bricksetup/docs").then(function(result) { 
  var data = result;
  console.log(data);
  vm.myfield(data.rows);


  //data.rows.forEach(function(row){
      //vm.data.push(row.value)
 // })
   //vm.myfield(data.rows[3].value.Name);
});

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

A screenshot how my data looks on console:

[image: Screen with data on my console]

I created the 2 Div to display them with my javascript

Any help appreciated

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Can you please read through the question and see if you can improve on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `foreach` fine but your approach to working with form data is not the Knockout-way. You should change the `select` code to use the knockout version and then have some JavaScript listen (`subscribe`) to changes on that.

So first we'll at the options to the view model a long with the property that is set when something is selected:

```
self.selectDivs = ko.observableArray(['Properties', 'Implements']);
self.selectedDiv = ko.observable();
```

Then we'll replace you `select` code with this:

```
<select class="browser-default" data-bind="options: $root.selectDivs,
                                                    value: $root.selectedDiv,
                                                    optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
```

Basically what this does is to set the `self.selectedDiv` value when you choose something.

Next step is to only show your divs when the respective option is selected. This is done by using the `visible` binding:

```
<div data-bind="visible: $root.selectedDiv() == 'Properties'" id="Properties">
    <p>Properties</p>
```

.. and the same for the other section that you have:

```
<div data-bind="visible: $root.selectedDiv() == 'Implements'" id="Implements">
    <p>Implements</p>
```

(note: `$root` is your `ViewModel` instance. This is the way to access the top most parent of your data)

I've put all of this in a <kbd>[working example](http://codepen.io/mblarsen/pen/YqGeab)</kbd> that shows all this, along with some other suggested changes.

Comment: @Muli, glad to help. The main take-away not rely to much on jQuery-style web-development and think of the view as data, hence the name view model :)

Comment: do you know any online resources for learning `KO` besides the documentation ?

Comment: @Muli not really—sorry to say